# How to create a thread safe EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: java, multithreading, orm, jpa

I'm working on an application that needs to do some database operations.

I created a static variable for `EntityManagerFactory` and initializeded it in the method that gets called by the application

```
 if (emf == null) {
      emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("example");
 }

 try {
      em = emf.createEntityManager();
 } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error(ex.getMessage());
 }
```

Is this thread-safe? If I create the `EntityManagerFactory` in a synchronized block, the number of the waiting threads increases and crashes the application.

I looked at the docs to see whether the `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` is thread-safe without any success.

Please direct me to the right resources.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An easy way to "solve" this would be to use a helper class (a la `HibernateUtil`) and to initialize the `EntityManagerFactory` in a static initialization block. Something like this:

```
public class JpaUtil { 
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf;

    static {
        try {
            factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPu");
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            logger.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed", ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

   ...

}
```

And the "problem" is gone.

Comment: I did that before. But, some people feel that its not a good practice to initialize in the static blocks. Is that right?

Comment: @Vanchinathan That's really a typical approach when you're not in a managed environment and I don't see anything wrong with it. Now, if you provide some arguments against it, we could discuss them but until then, I maintain this recommendation.

Comment: The one argument that I always get is , having code in the static blocks, hinders testing. We follow Test Driven development strictly. So I need something that is also easier to test.

Comment: @Vanchinathan Still, you want to initialize the EMF only once which is why the above pattern is used. You should then use this code to obtain an EntityManager and inject it in the classes that need it (and those will be nicely testable).

Comment: The question was is createEntityManager() thread-safe? The answer after looking at some code and the class definition is that it is "application-wide" in scope IS thread-safe. The EntityManager instances however are NOT thread-safe. So this works although I would recommend a simple Singleton pattern to get the handle to the factory. The reason is that `static` blocks are beholden to the container class-loader as to when they load. This could be BEFORE the persistence-manager framework is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

I am not seeing any issues with the static block approach. Or you can do the same in the below manner which is a Singleton pattern with double-lock check

```
public class JPAHelper {

 private static JPAHelper myHelper = new JPAHelper();
 private static EntityManagerFactory myFactory = null;

 /**
  * Private constructor. Implementing synchronization with double-lock check
  */
 private JPAHelper() {

  if(myFactory == null) {
   synchronized (JPAHelper.class) {

    // This second check will be true only for the first thread entering the block incase 
    // of thread race
    if(myFactory == null) {
     myFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyUnit");
    }
   }
  }
 }

 /**
  * Static Accessor Method
  * @return
  */
 public static JPAHelper getInstance() {
  if(myHelper == null) {
   myHelper = new JPAHelper();
  }
  return myHelper;
 }


 public EntityManagerFactory getJPAFactory() {
  return myFactory;
 }
```

And you will call

```
EntityManager myManager = JPAhelper.getInstance().getJPAFactory().createEntityManager();
```

Comment: The Singleton pattern is recommended but there is no need (or effect) of using a double-checked lock. createEntityManagerFactory() is thread-safe already and will return the same handle to the same factory in any case. A properly written Singleton that loads the factory statically will always return the one handle. Double-check locks do not work in real-world application containers/systems. See this: [http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

Comment: Double-check locks WORK in real-world applications. The above code should declare myFactory as volatile. The same referenced article explains "Fixing Double-Checked Locking using Volatile"

Answer (score 1):

You need to put locks on an object when you are creating the `emf`. You *can* put the locks on the `emf` object itself, but that's not best practice. Create another object:

```
private object factoryLockObject = new object();
```

and put your locks on it while creating the factory

```
lock(factoryLockObject) {
   if (emf == null) {
      emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("example");
   }
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: What difference does that make? I'll give it a try.

Comment: This will add an object lock on the factoryLockObject and cause any other threads wanting to access it to wait until the lock is lifted (at the final curly brace).
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Still, will it not block the threads? If Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("example");
 is thread safe, then I dont need to synchronize it.

Comment: I don't know whether Persistence is internally thread-safe. The locking that I've shown WILL cause any threads wanting to execute this block of code to wait until the first thread is done with it. This is why your IF has to go inside the lock too.

Answer (score 1):

Whether `createEntityManagerFactory()` is thread-safe or not, you need some strategy so that it is invoked only once. In other words, that question is irrelevant, because you must ensure that only one thread calls it.

If simply waiting for another thread to create the factory crashes your application, what will happen when every thread creates its own, clobbering the work of other threads in the process?

The code you show should be inside a `synchronized` block, or it is not thread safe.

Comment: There is no need for a strategy to only call the factory once. A lookup has to be done in any case and a Singleton pattern will ensure the handle to the current (one) instance is always returned. All of the calling threads will get the same reference to the same factory. There is no need for synchronization and additionally will create a performance issue as threads are fighting to gain the monitor just be returned the one-and-only factory handle anyway.

Comment: @DarrellTeague How does a caller determine whether a factory is shared or not and thus, whether it should be closed by that caller? According to the OP, initialization of the factory is time-consuming. Creating multiple unnecessary instances throughout the life of the application seems a far bigger performance problem than any contention that might occur during the instant it takes to simply synchronize and read a variable, once initialized.

Comment: I am using Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(ID) as a static, singular instance and it is thread-safe. What has to be safe-guarded are the instances of EntityManager from EMF.createEntityManager(). That needs to be inside a given method, followed by creating a transaction, committing it and then calling close() on the EntityManager (which is the same as J2EE DataSource Connection.close() to release the JDBC Connection back to the pool-manager). This is the same pattern as pre-JPA with DataSource and JDBC Connection via a pool-manager.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is: YES, createEntityManagerFactory() is thread-safe based on the class documentation, source and real-world application results.

The Singleton Pattern answer is most correct for avoiding an additional call to retrieve the one factory handle efficiently but note there is no need for a double-check lock as commented earlier.