# I get a PersistenceException and I cannot understand why

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am running a web service using EclipseLink and it works good. But sometimes I get an exception saying "Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit". I i don´t have a clue why I am getting this. Everything else seems to work and the exception doesn´t seem to disturb the application, it is just beeing catched.

```
Exception Description: Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [MyLibPU] in invalid state [Undeployed]
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28017] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [MyLibPU] in invalid state [Undeployed]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:121)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
....
....
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28017] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [MyLibPU] in invalid state [Undeployed]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.cannotPredeploy(EntityManagerSetupException.java:202)
    ... 30 more
```

In the exception I can find a trace to a line in a method:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyLibPU");
```

Why am I getting this?

**EDIT**
This is the output I get when eclipselink logging is set to `FINEST`.

```
[EL Finest]: 2012-04-23 15:19:06.025--ServerSession(2134178364)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--End undeploying Persistence Unit MyLibPU; session file:/home/Rox/MyLib/trunk/MyLib/build/classes/_MyLibPU; state Undeployed; factoryCount 0
[EL Finest]: 2012-04-23 15:19:06.025--ServerSession(2113649746)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--Begin undeploying Persistence Unit MyLibPU; session file:/home/Rox/MyLib/trunk/MyLib/src/_MyLibPU; state Deployed; factoryCount 3
[EL Finest]: 2012-04-23 15:19:06.025--ServerSession(2113649746)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--End undeploying Persistence Unit MyLibPU; session file:/home/Rox/MyLib/trunk/MyLib/src/_MyLibPU; state Deployed; factoryCount 2
Apr 23, 2012 3:19:06 PM com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler invoke
SEVERE: Exception [EclipseLink-28017] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [MyLibPU] in invalid state [Undeployed]
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28017] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [MyLibPU] in invalid state [Undeployed]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:956)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:121)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.mylib.MyImplementation.getPersons(MyImplementation.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:235)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:246)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:85)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:299)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:593)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:668)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:640)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28017] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.0.v20110202-r8913): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Unable to predeploy PersistenceUnit [MyLibPU] in invalid state [Undeployed]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.cannotPredeploy(EntityManagerSetupException.java:202)
    ... 30 more

[EL Finer]: 2012-04-23 15:20:06.003--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-61,5,main])--fixUNC: before fixing: url = file:/home/Rox/MyLib/build/classes/, authority = , file = /home/Rox/MyLib/build/classes/ (There is no English translation for this message.)
[EL Finer]: 2012-04-23 15:20:06.012--Thread(Thread[pool-1-thread-61,5,main])--fixUNC: after fixing: url = file:/home.....
```

**EDIT 2**
My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyLibPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.mylib.Person</class>
    <class>com.mylib.Group</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MY_DB"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="MyPassword"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>;
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>;
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>;
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Is there more to the exception?  EclipseLink is getting an error creating the persistence unit, so if there isn't more to the error, you will need to turn logging to finest to find out more: <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>.  Obtaining a factory later on may 'work' since much of the unit might have been initialized before the error occured, but there is no way to tell what wasn't.  Exceptions creating the factory should not be discarded.

Comment: @Chris: Sorry for the late reply. Look at my edit in my post above and you will se the output when EclipseLink logging is set to FINEST. You will se the whole exception in my edit above. Can you figure it out what the problem is? I can not. =/

Comment: There should be more stack trace even after your edit . Check server. Any way post your `persistence.xml` . Something is wrong there . Could just even be invalid XML that is not getting parsed.

Comment: @Shahzeb: There are no more lines of the stacktrace. I posted the whole exception. Look at my second edit in my post above to see the persistence.xml.

Comment: An error occurred before this, check your server logs.  Restart your server before running your test as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is sporadic, maybe this mean it's a timing issue. Also, apparently you are creating the factory multiple times during the lifecycle of the app (let me know if I'm wrong). So, it coud be that concurrent requests to your web app trigger the concurrent creation of factories. This case might not be supported.

It is anyway good to create the factory only once. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711439/how-to-create-a-thread-safe-entitymanagerfactory) on how to do it. Then you can concurrently call `createEntityManager` on it -- this method is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with undeploying Hibernate.  It looks like you're running into them when you try to undeploy and redeploy.  Do you have a problem when you do a full server restart?

EDIT: Sorry, you clearly said you were using EclipseLink, not sure why I thought you were using Hibernate.

In any case, this line in your log is worrying:

```
[EL Finest]: 2012-04-23 15:19:06.025--ServerSession(2113649746)--Thread(Thread[Finalizer,8,system])--Begin undeploying Persistence Unit MyLibPU; session file:/home/Rox/MyLib/trunk/MyLib/src/_MyLibPU; state Deployed; factoryCount 3
```

I'm not sure what `factoryCount` means but I don't like that it is > 1.  Most worrying, though, is "Begin undeploying Persistence Unit MyLibPU".  Why is the PU being undeployed? I thought it was because you were undeploying the app, but in your comments you say "The errors can occur anytime during the application´s lifetime and only occur 2-5 times every 24 hours."  In that case, you need to figure out what is triggering the undeploy.

Comment: I can check that and return with the answer. But I am not running Hibernate. I am running EclipseLink. The errors can occur anytime during the application´s lifetime and only occur 2-5 times every 24 hours and doesn´t make any trouble or something. They just occur. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do not use static constructors or similar constructions when working with databases. This might avoid a lo to troubles. Try to insert pauses and explicit log commands in your code to find the error to find how far your code go.